# Problem with Django One-to-One Table Primary Key Assignment - "ID" not found and "NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FAILED"

Tags: python, django, database, model

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. I simply have a table with a one-to-one relationship with the User table. The code for the model, in part, is:

```
class Client(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When the table is created and I try to access the table information from within admin, it says no "id" is assigned, but it does assign a field that it generates automatically called 'user_id' and that field is populated with the primary key. It just doesn't seem to be recognizing it as the primary key, or accessing data because the "id" is not found.

When I delete primary key=True, and leave it as a OnetoOneField without assigning it as the primary key,as follows

```
class Client(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

it doesn't save and I get an Integrity error:

```
IntegrityError at /client_intake/1/
NOT NULL constraint failed: intake_client.user_id
```

Apparently without the primary key set it tries to save the user_id field as a null value. So, I cannot set the OnetoOne as primary key and I can't set it without it being the primary key without getting an error. It only saves when the primary key is true but then I can't access the data even though the user_id field contains the primary key because it says that no "id" is found.

My admin.py includes this:

```
    list_display = ('user_id', 'client_lname', 'client_fname',
                'client_mname', 'submitted')
```

I get the error that no id exists when I click on the user_id field. I have spent about a week trying to figure this out and tried everything under the sun including deleting my database and migrations at least a dozen times while trying different aspects of the key assignment. I am at a dead end. Can ANYONE help me here?

Here is my views.py file:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def client_intake_req(request, pk=None, client=None):
# First test to see if there is an existing model for client
# If there is an existing form, populate and render it; otherwise create
# a new one
if pk:
    try:
        client = Client.objects.get(user_id=pk)
        # If the object exists:
        submitted = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ClientIntakeForm(request.POST, instance=client)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('?submitted=True')
        else:
            form = ClientIntakeForm(instance=client)
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True
        return render(request, 'client_intake.html',{'form': form, 
                'submitted': submitted})
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        submitted = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ClientIntakeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('?submitted=True')
        else:
            form = ClientIntakeForm()
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True
        return render(request, 'client_intake.html',
            {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})
```

Comment: Something really weird is going on. After trying a number of parameter names instead of 'user' for the primary key variable, I tried 'id' and that works. There is now a variable in the table called 'id_id' as well as the 'id'. No other name works for this variable.  Its not optimal, but as a workaround I guess it's fine, but it doesn't make any sense.  Does anyone know of or have any explanation?